# Android: Error in passing argument for Extras

Tags: android

I tried to pass extras from one activity to another activity. I also have a class named Objects which holds the objects of the extras.

On my first activity, I wrote this:

```
 private OnClickListener top_listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent top = new Intent(Main.this, TopProject.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putParcelable("project_title", Objects);
                    startActivity(top);
        }
        };
```

**But there's a syntax error on this line: b.putParcelable("project_title", Objects); it said 'Objects' cannot be resolved to a variable. Should I declare something else first or what?** Thank you

and this is my Objects Class:

```
public class Objects implements Parcelable{

   String project_title = "project title";
   String organization_title = "organization title";
   String keyword = "keyword";
   String short_code = "short code";
   String project_description = "description";
   String smallImageUrl = "smallImageUrl";
   String bigImageUrl = "bigImageUrl";
   String price= "price";
   String country= "country";


    public static ArrayList<Project> projectsList = new ArrayList<Project>();

    public Objects(String project_title, String organization_title, String keyword, String short_code, String project_description, String smallImageUrl, String bigImageUrl, String price, String country) {
        this.project_title = project_title;
        this.organization_title = organization_title;
        this.keyword = keyword;
        this.short_code = short_code;
        this.project_description = project_description;
        this.smallImageUrl = smallImageUrl;
        this.bigImageUrl = bigImageUrl;
        this.price = price;
        this.country = country;

    }

     private Objects(Parcel parcel) {
            project_title = parcel.readString();
            organization_title = parcel.readString();
            keyword = parcel.readString();
            short_code = parcel.readString();
            project_description = parcel.readString();
            smallImageUrl = parcel.readString();
            bigImageUrl = parcel.readString();
            price = parcel.readString();
            country = parcel.readString();
            //projectsList = parcel.readList();
        }

    public int describeContents() {

        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        parcel.writeString(project_title);
        parcel.writeString(organization_title);
        parcel.writeString(keyword);
        parcel.writeString(short_code);
        parcel.writeString(project_description);
        parcel.writeString(smallImageUrl);
        parcel.writeString(bigImageUrl);
        parcel.writeString(price);
        parcel.writeString(country);
        parcel.writeList(projectsList);
    }

    public String getProjectTitle(){
        return project_title;
    }

    public String getOrganizationTitle(){
        return organization_title;
    }

    public String getProjectDescription(){
        return project_description;
    }

    public String getKeyword(){
        return keyword;
    }

    public String getShortcode(){
        return short_code;
    }

    public String getSmallImageUrl(){
        return smallImageUrl;
    }

    public String getBigImageUrl(){
        return bigImageUrl;
    }

    public String getPrice(){
        return price;
    }

    public String getCountry(){
        return country;
    }

    public void setProjectTitle(String project_title){
        this.project_title = project_title;
    }

    public void setOrganizationTitle(String organization_title){
        this.organization_title = organization_title;
    }

    public void setProjectDescription(String project_description){
        this.project_description = project_description;
    }

    public void setKeyword(String keyword){
        this.keyword = keyword;
    }

    public void setShortcode(String short_code){
        this.short_code = short_code;
    }

    public void setSmallImageUrl(String smallImageUrl){
        this.smallImageUrl = smallImageUrl;
    }

    public void setBigImageUrl(String bigImageUrl){
        this.bigImageUrl = bigImageUrl;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price){
        this.price = price;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country){
        this.country = country;
    }

    public static Creator<Objects> CREATOR
            = new Creator<Objects>() {
        public Objects createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            return new Objects(parcel);
        }

        public Objects[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Objects[size];
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b.putParcelable("project_title", Objects);
```

This means pretty nothing. You have to supply an instance of your class. Something like :

```
b.putParcelable("project_title", new Objects());
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a simple class with primitives and Serializables only, make use of Serializable, not Parcelable. It will make your life a lot easier. The Objects object passed must also be an instance, as stated in other answers

e.g.

```
Objects object = new Objects(); //assuming Objects implements Serializable
bundle.putSerializable("blahblah", object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass "Oject" as an arguement as it deifnes the name of the clsaa.Provice the ref of that class over there.